# Country and region selector are not rendering with useState, does anyone have a solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

> I have tried to make it work country and region selector but when it
> comes to selecting region it is not responding instead, it is
> redirecting to choose country all over again any solutions would be
> great

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Register from "../register/Register";
import "./people.scss";

import { AiFillHeart, AiFillWechat } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { CountryDropdown, RegionDropdown } from 'react-country-region-selector';

function People() {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.data);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();

  // fetching users from DB
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((users) => setUsers(users));
  }, []);

  // Countries selector
  const initialState = {
    country: '',
    region: ''
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const { country, region } = state;

  // Age selector
  const populateOptions = () => {
    const optionsNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 18; i <= 100; i++) {
      optionsNumbers.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)
    }
    return optionsNumbers;
  }

  // state loggedIn
  if (data.token && data.user._id) {
    return (
      <section className="people">
        <div className="filter-search-bar">
          <div>
            <span>Seeking: </span>
            <select id="select">
              <option id="male" value="male">male</option>
              <option id="female" value="female">female</option>
              <option id="all" value="all">any</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>Country: </span>
            <CountryDropdown
              value={country}
              onChange={(val) => setState({ country: val })} />
            <RegionDropdown
              country={country}
              value={region}
              onChange={(val) => setState({ region: val })} />
          </div>
          <div className="age-slider">
            <span>Age: </span>
            <select defaultValue="18" id="min-age">
              {populateOptions()}
            </select>
            <select defaultValue="40" id="max-age">
              {populateOptions()}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit"> Search Filter </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {users &&
          users.map((user, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="profile-card">
              <div className="image-container">
                <img className="profile-image" src={user.image} alt="profile_pic" />
              </div>

              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="bio-container">
                  <h3 className="card-title">{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</h3>
                  <p className="profile-text">{user.bio}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="card-icons-container">
                  <AiFillHeart color={"divghtpink"} size={25} />
                  <AiFillWechat color={"divghtpink"} size={25} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </section>
    );
  } else {
    return <Register />;
  }
}




export default People;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

    import Register from "../register/Register";
    import "./people.scss";

    import { AiFillHeart, AiFillWechat } from 'react-icons/ai';
    import { CountryDropdown, RegionDropdown } from 'react-country-region-selector';

    function People() {
      const data = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.data);
      const [users, setUsers] = useState();

      // fetching users from DB
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/users")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((users) => setUsers(users));
      }, []);

      // Countries selector
      const initialState = {
        country: '',
        region: ''
      }

      const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
      const { country, region } = state;

      // Age selector
      const populateOptions = () => {
        const optionsNumbers = [];
        for (let i = 18; i <= 100; i++) {
          optionsNumbers.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)
        }
        return optionsNumbers;
      }

      // state loggedIn
      if (data.token && data.user._id) {
        return (
          <section className="people">
            <div className="filter-search-bar">
              <div>
                <span>Seeking: </span>
                <select id="select">
                  <option id="male" value="male">male</option>
                  <option id="female" value="female">female</option>
                  <option id="all" value="all">any</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <span>Country: </span>
                <CountryDropdown
                  value={country}
                  onChange={(val) => setState({ country: val })} />
                <RegionDropdown
                  country={country}
                  value={region}
                  onChange={(val) => setState({ region: val })} />
              </div>
              <div className="age-slider">
                <span>Age: </span>
                <select defaultValue="18" id="min-age">
                  {populateOptions()}
                </select>
                <select defaultValue="40" id="max-age">
                  {populateOptions()}
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button type="submit"> Search Filter </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {users &&
              users.map((user, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="profile-card">
                  <div className="image-container">
                    <img className="profile-image" src={user.image} alt="profile_pic" />
                  </div>

                  <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="bio-container">
                      <h3 className="card-title">{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</h3>
                      <p className="profile-text">{user.bio}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="card-icons-container">
                      <AiFillHeart color={"divghtpink"} size={25} />
                      <AiFillWechat color={"divghtpink"} size={25} />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </section>
        );
      } else {
        return <Register />;
      }
    }


    export default People;
```

> I have tried to make it work country and region selector but when it
> comes to selecting region it is not responding instead, it is
> redirecting to choose country all over again any solutions would be
> great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is most probable the fact that you are confusing the way you update the state created with hooks with the way you are updating it in class components.

If you have this

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    country: '',
    region: ''
  }
```

To update the region you would not do this:

```
setState({region: 'new region'});
```

but this

```
setState({...state, region: 'new region' })
```

this way keeping the rest of the state intact.

Comment: Thanks it really works

Comment: if the answer helped you make sure to accept it :)